# Individual test function works, but chaining them get: "FOREIGN KEY constraint failed"

Tags: python, django, selenium, foreign-keys

I can run each individual test (by calling the function directly), but if I chain them, I've got an error when the Test enters the next function (the first one always running fine).

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed`
```

(I can change the order of the functions, the error is still on the second one).

**test_mainpage.py**

```
class MainPage_testing(StaticLiveServerTestCase):

   @classmethod
   def setUpClass(cls):
      super(MainPage_testing, cls).setUpClass()
      cls.pwd = 'selenium20!!!'
      cls.user_1 = UserFactory(password=cls.pwd)
      cls.selenium = WebDriver()

      cls.selenium.get('{}'.format(cls.live_server_url))
      cls.find(By.NAME, 'login').send_keys(cls.user_1.username)
      cls.find(By.NAME, 'password').send_keys(cls.pwd)
      cls.find(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[type='submit']").click()

  def test_Create_a_post(self):
      text = Texts.objects.create(owner=self.user_1, title="post",
          text="this is a post")
      ... 

  def test_Create_a_comment(self):
      text2 = Texts.objects.create(owner=self.user_1, title="comment",
          text="this is a comment") # <-- Triggers the error
      ...
```

**models.py**

```
class Texts(models):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    title = models.CharField( max_length=200)  
    text = models.TextField()
```

**factories.py**

```
class UserFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = User
    
    username = factory.Faker('first_name')
    password = factory.PostGenerationMethodCall('set_password', '12345')
```

I can run `test_Create_a_comment` individually, but if running the whole test `test_mainpage`, the error appears at `text2 = Texts.objects.create(owner=self.user_1, title="comment", text="this is a comment")`

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed`
```

Comment: Is there a constraint on **owner** field of Texts model? could you provide TextsFactory code?

Comment: @blondelg Sorry, I've completed the question. I've removed the TextsFactory though since the error is still present when simply using `Texts.objects.creste(..)`